# How i can insert a JSON object into MySQL database?

Tags: php, json

Hi i have been serached for this issue , but i did not find anything .

The question is simple:

**How i can insert a json object into mysql databse in order to retrieve it later, the json objects is as the following:**

```
$CHE=mysqli_real_escape_string($conexio,$_POST['checkE']);//json object 1
$CHT=mysqli_real_escape_string($conexio,$_POST['checkT']);//json object 2
$CHF=mysqli_real_escape_string($conexio,$_POST['checkF']);//json object 3
$CHD=mysqli_real_escape_string($conexio,$_POST['checkD']);//json object 4
$CHA=mysqli_real_escape_string($conexio,$_POST['checkA']);//json object 5


//$query_it=mysqli_query($conexio," INSERT INTO menu values('".$personal_name."','".utf8_decode($CHE)."','".utf8_decode($CHT)."','".utf8_decode($CHF)."','".utf8_decode($CHD)."','".utf8_decode($CHA)."')");
```

**one time the code has been run, we can see the data into mysql table as the follow:**

```
{"menuE":{"Introducción":{},"Visualización":{}}}
```

**but not is for example as the follow(thats is, with the slashes):**

```
"{\"title\":\"Sachin vs shoaib akhtar and company..Unseen (BAAP BAAP HI HOTA HAI ) ....flv\",\"titleEsc\":\"Sachin vs shoaib akhtar and company..Unseen (BAAP BAAP HI HOTA HAI ) ....flv\",\"url\":\"http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WOJlDpoL7tw\",\"pageUrl\":\"http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WOJlDpoL7tw\",\"cannonicalUrl\":\"www.youtube.com\",\"description\":\"Sachin hitting cluless shoaib akhtar and company everywhere in ground..This is one f many innings where shoaib akhtar was brutually assaulted by sachin tendu...\",\"descriptionEsc\":\"Sachin hitting cluless shoaib akhtar and company everywhere in ground..This is one f many innings where shoaib akhtar was brutually assaulted by sachin tendu...\",\"images\":\"http://i2.ytimg.com/vi/WOJlDpoL7tw/hqdefault.jpg\",\"video\":\"yes\",\"videoIframe\":\"<iframe id=\\\"20131122120255WOJlDpoL7tw\\\" style=\\\"display: none; margin-bottom: 5px;\\\" width=\\\"499\\\" height=\\\"368\\\" src=\\\"http://www.youtube.com/embed/WOJlDpoL7tw\\\" frameborder=\\\"0\\\" allowfullscreen></iframe>\"}";
```

**cause if it saved with the structure in above , we can retrieve the information doing  the following:**

```
$array=json_decode($objstring,true);
//var_dump($array);


foreach($array  as $titol=>$llista){

    echo "TITOL: ".$titol."   LLISTA:  ".$llista;;
    echo"<br>";
    }
```

so how i can save the json objects ?

Thanks

Comment: json is just text. you'd insert into the db like any other text.

Comment: yes , but the slashes does not appear, how i can save it in the same format as i describe above (with slashes)

Comment: Serialized objects in a database or fingernails down a blackboard ... tough call.

Comment: the version with slashes is NOT valid json. unless you're double-encoding the json, which is rather pointless.

Comment: how i can improve the code? give an example please!

Answer (score 0):

I would try to stringify them with `json_encode()`

```
$CHE=mysqli_real_escape_string($conexio,json_encode($_POST['checkE']));//json object 1
```

Comment: now i can save the json object as the above structure , but  this doesn't work, because i don't retrieve any array:while ($fila = mysqli_fetch_assoc($UserMenu)) {
   
 $array=json_decode($fila['equipos'],true);
var_dump($array);


foreach($array  as $titol=>$llista){

   echo "<b>";
   echo "Titol".$titol;
   echo "</b>";
   foreach($array[$titol] as $submenu){                 

    echo "</b>";
    $td.="Submenu".$submenu;
    $td.="</b>";
    
     }
}the warning is as the follow:Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Comment: which line is givinf the error? I think it's `foreach($array[$titol] as $submenu){ `

Comment: the problem is when i trying retrieve the json structure from database